# XCOPY Copied files and folders as a file

Tags: batch, xcopy

Today i had some problems with a laptop, and i had to reinstall the windows on it, while i was in the recovery console, i used XCOPY batch command to copy files and folders from c:\users\*USERNAME*\*.* to a folder on another partition. The problem is the command created a file with the save folder name that contains all my information. Is there any way to get the information back?

Comment: xcopy has a parameters to specify that the target is a directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xcopy has a parameters to specify that the target is a directory. Using that might prevent problems like this in the future.

It will be hard, if not impossible to restore the files. They are just copied one after another without any indication of where one starts and another ends. Probably no filenames stored, no size information.. It may work if you got only a couple of files that each have a clear file header, but otherwise you're doomed.

Comment: My luck was that the files were successfully restored by a HDD data recoverer. The all files that were stored in the ~2gb single file were so damaged that I was only able to restore some photos as they still had an intact header.